# compare datatable results with form values

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datatable

How do i compare the row returned by my datatable with that of the form values and if the form values are different then `MessageBox.Show("Would you like to update?");`

Here is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SQLiteCommand command = m_dbConnection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select * from rdpdirectory where company = @company order by company asc";

command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@company", txtCompany.Text));
SQLiteDataAdapter db = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
db.Fill(dt);

DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
keyColumns[0] = dt.Columns["company"];
dt.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;

DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
```

Here are my textboxes:

```
txtCompany.Text 
txtServer.Text 
txtUserName.Text 
txtPassword.Text
```

**Edit: I tried this:**
I thought about trying: `if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)` but that will always return a row as the record is in the database. I need to check if the record is the SAME or DIFFERENT compared to the form values.

Comment: Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the statement as below

```
select count(*) from rdpdirectory where company = @company and Server =@Server and UserName =@UserName and Password =@Password"
```

set the all parameter values as like you already did for `company`

then

```
int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

if rowCount is equal to 1 means you don't need to update the record

```
        using (SQLiteCommand command = m_dbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "select count(*) from rdpdirectory where company = @company and Server =@Server and UserName =@UserName and Password =@Password";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", txtCompany.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server", txtServer.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

            int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            if (rowCount <1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Would you like to update?");
            }
        }
```

Comment: The SQL you provided returns no dt.. and the command text is NULL... :S

Comment: no, if there is a row which matching current values in the form means there is no update. if row count is zero means you have to update

Comment: I dont think the DT is getting returned in any case.. Therefore its always ZERO and always updating! grrr